# How to set height to 'auto' of a Custom Lightning Record Page Template with Scrolling Ability

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Actually my requirement is to set the Custom lightning Record Page Template with Scrolling ability and auto height set.

There are two issues regarding Custom Lightning Record Page Template, either of one can solve the main issue.

1. When we set Custom Lightning Record Page height to some pixel like 90px or 100px or with other measurements, then we are able to have Scrolling ability of the Record Page.But in this Case the issue is Height is not dynamic, so when we minimise the screen or set the screen zoom level then Page looks weird i.e. blank container down to the page even if we don't have any information there.
2. When we set Height styling component to Auto, then above issue resolves but Issue arises is It overrides the Scrolling ability of Lightning Record Page Template Component.

CSS:

```css
.THIS.container { 
    max-height: 100vh; 
    display: flex; 
    height: calc(100% - 100px); width: 100% 
} 

.THIS .scroll-y { 
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: Hii @nbrown
Sure I can.Here's my code.

Comment: CSS:
.THIS.container {
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: 100%
}

.THIS .scroll-y {
    overflow-y: auto;
}